# How to convert XML file to Doc file?

Tags: c#, xml

My **XML** file has following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <note>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend! </body>
    </note>
```

I have to convert it to doc file. I am using **Spire.Doc** component for its conversion. But it is giving below error:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index "

I am using below code snippet:

```
 Document doc = new Document();
 doc.LoadFromFile(textBox1.Text, FileFormat.Xml);
 doc.SaveToFile(DocfileLocation, FileFormat.Doc);
```

Is there any other method to convert it ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, I've edited your question, here is why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you have presented it. Could it be that you are not escaping "\" characters or similar? As a test try to save the xml file as sample.xml in the same folder as the executable will be compiled to and run this snippet instead:

```
 Document doc = new Document();
 doc.LoadFromFile("sample.xml", FileFormat.Xml);
 doc.SaveToFile("test.doc", FileFormat.Doc);
```

That should give you a new .doc file with the content of the .xml file in it

Comment: After applying this code snippet, i am getting this error: "There are no sections present in the document". The document it is creating, it is not showing contents of xml, instead it is showing encoding of utf-8 format. But i want to display the content of nodes of xml.

Comment: Does the sample.xml file you are using to test with contain actual xml data?